# Geoserver CQL filter with many “IN” conditions

Tags: geoserver, cql

I am using Geoserver to generate colored regions on a map a wms link, CQL condition can contain a long string of "IN". Max number of INs could be up to 1-2 thousands. I tried to divide it into 3 requests, but such filters are loading the processors very much. Is there any way to get the result and not use long CQL filters?
[image: CQL filter example]

Comment: I thought about it, hope it will help. Seems the problem is with very long URL processing with GET.
I will give it a try.
BR,
Andrey

Comment: slightly off topic: maybe you don't need to build and send thousands of Ids, but rather a higher level filter (like `field1 is not null and field2 > field3`). Or if that's not possible, the ID list could be saved in a table on the server side and you join the ID list to the layer. In the screenshot you have provided, on the map side, the filters seems pretty generic so sending a huge list of IDs seems overkilled

Comment: Hi JGH, thanks for your remark.

Comment: Hi JGH, thanks for your remark. The matter is that the list of IDs (RDAs) is generated depending on the radio amateur callsign in the browser form, and the list of IDs is a result of XHR to another site. And it can not be described with logic like (like field1 is not null and field2 > field3), it is just a list of results. So, the table is dynamic, could you please point me how to save it on server side (you mean in geoserver, right)? Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Not necessarily in GeoServer. It could be your webapp fetching and storing (maybe in a database) the data from the external API, then GeoServer can return a joined view between the raw data and this user specific list. Of course it means you need to work per user on the server side, clean up obsolete data etc

Comment: So, at 1st step I need to put the table in some table in MySQL DB. The regions layer is just a shape file datastore, and I need to filter it according to the SQL table. So, is it possible in principle? Or  I need to convert shape to a geo DB and then to join it as a SQL view? Sorry for dummy`s questions.

Answer (score 2):

The list of IDs still need to be communicated, and the WMS protocol is entirely stateless, so it needs to be communicated at every request.
What you can do, is to switch to POST requests instead of GET, putting all the query parameters into a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload (same as if you were posting a HTML form).